# Gambling odds and implied probability intuition?

Tags: probability, intuition, gambling

I’ve learned that to calculate implied probability based on a gambling odds, you use the following formula:

Implied probability of win %= stake/ total payout

For example, if my fractional odds for team a to win are 5/1 (bet 1 dollar to win 5 dollars if team a wins), then the implied probability = 1/6.

Is there any intuition to why this is the case considering probability is the number of successful outcomes/ total number of outcomes?

Comment: Assume the payout is $~\dfrac{1}{k}~$ where $k$ is any positive real number.  This implies that you wager $1$, and if you win, you get back $(1 + k)$.  This implies that in order for the proposition to be a break even proposition, your probability of winning must be $~\dfrac{1}{k+1}.$  This is because you want the probability of winning times the payout to equal $1$, which is your original investment.  You have that $$\frac{1}{k+1} \times (1+k) = 1.$$

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks a lot for the response. Could you please break that down a little bit for me? 
- Why would the payout be assumed to be 1/k? & can you  please explain that last formula you made and the intuition behind it? I appreciate your help.

Comment: I am assuming that if you wager $1$, that you will get back $(k+1)$, where $k$ is any positive number.  So, I am making $k$ into a **variable**.  The idea is that **any** payout ratio can be expressed in the form of $1$ to $k$, where $k$ is some positive real number.  Looking at it from that perspective, my comment indicates that for the betting proposition to be break even, the probability of winning must be $\frac{1}{1+k}.$  As an example, if you are required to invest $2$ to win $3$, that would be expressed as $1$ to win $1.5$, so in that instance, $k$ would equal $1.5.$

Comment: Similarly, if you are required to invest $4$ to win $1$, that would be expressed as $1$ to $(1/4)$, so in that instance, $k$ would equal $(1/4).$

Comment: So, in general, if you are required to invest $A$ to win $B$, this is equivalent to investing $1$ to win $\dfrac{B}{A}.$  So, you have that then, $k = \dfrac{B}{A}.$

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks so much. And the way you related your equation to probability was the idea of expected value (where expected value= probability x outcome)? I am just unsure of how you made the jump of your payout ratio x payout equation to a probability.

Comment: If you invest $1$, and the total payout is $(1 + k)$, and the **break even** probability is $P$, then $P$ must satisfy the equation $$P \times (1 + k) = 1.$$  This is because you want your expected return to exactly match your original investment of $1$.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3874939/339790)